# How to manipulate a folder of excel files in R?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

So I have a folder of excel files all identical in format. Here's a simplified version of what I'm working with:

```
country   count  year
USA       23232  2019
USA        3993  2019
RUSSIA    67574  2019
JAPAN        31  2019
JAPAN       535  2019
```

So I would like to do the following to every file in my folder

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country, year) %>% 
  summarize(count = sum(count))
```

In one file this will look like:

```
  country     year count
1 JAPAN       2019   566
2 RUSSIA      2019 67574
3 USA         2019 27225
```

So how can I do this for every file in my folder, again they are identical. The end goal would be one dataframe with all the file's count data in it. Tidyverse preferred

Comment: can you give an example of your directory structure in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can be useful. You build a function that reads the excel file (I have used `sheet = 1` but you can change it). After that you process and assign a key variable with the name of the file. Then, you create a list to do the process and finally bind the content using `bind_rows()`. Here the code:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
#Extract files
vec <- list.files(path = 'Your/Path/Here',pattern = '.xlsx')
#Function
readprocess <- function(x)
{
  y <- read_excel(x,1)
  z <- y %>% 
    group_by(country, year) %>% 
    summarize(count = sum(count)) %>% mutate(Filename=x)
  return(z)
}
#Apply
List <- lapply(vec,readprocess)
#Bind
df <- do.call(bind_rows,List)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
folder_path <- "insert_path_here"
files <- list.files(path=folder_path)

results <- lapply(files, function(x) {
    df <- read.csv(paste0(folder_path, "/", x))
    df <- df %>% 
         group_by(country, year) %>% 
         summarize(count = sum(count))
    }
)
df_results <- do.call(bind_rows, results)
```

Alternatively, you could just define your files into a list manually, but the gist of it is that script will:

- Run through each file in that list, and for each file:
- Read in the spreadsheet
- Perform data manipulation
- Binds all the results into a dataframe